# Is the pictured plant an Aloe kilifiensis?

Tags: identification, houseplants, aloe

Bought from a local store, it's listed as an [Aloe kilifiensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_kilifiensis), but unsure if it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is labled as Aloe CV. Fang by [this seller](https://www.ebay.com/itm/110859826680?rmvSB=true).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is [Aloe 'Jurrasic Chameleon'](https://zielony-parapet.pl/sukulenty/276-aloe-jurrasic-chameleon-aloes-0000000000276.html). Compare please with this store. This is a specialist store for lovers of succulents. He certainly sells correctly marked plants. Your plant is only a little less stained, maybe it has little light.